# How to convert a website to Kibana Plugin and add as custom plugin to dashboard?

Tags: kibana, kibana-plugin

How do I create a custom plugin in Kibana?
Are there any online resources?

Can I convert a website I created into a Kibana Plugin? If yes, in what language should I code the website for it to be compatible with Kibana? Should I use React JS or Angular JS?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana plugins are written in Typescript and use React JS.

There's some documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/external-plugin-development.html).

If you want to review a relatively simple example of a plugin (client side only code), take a look at my latest plugin - [customise kibana theme](https://github.com/lizozom/custom-kibana-theme).